# Not able to automatic generate ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt, though proxyserver.jks and jmeter.log file updates

Tags: java, jmeter-5.0

Not able to automatic generate ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt, though proxyserver.jks and jmeter.log file updates, also jmeter.log show error -=
2023-12-26 19:10:34,828 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Creating HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder Root CA in C:\Users\apache-jmeter-5.5\apache-jmeter-5.5\bin\proxyserver.jks, ensure you install certificate in your Browser for recording
2023-12-26 19:10:40,718 ERROR o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Could not initialise key store
java.io.IOException: Command failed, code: 1
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentpath:"C:\windows\system32\Aternity\Java\JavaHookLoader.dll"="C:\ProgramData\Aternity\hooks"
keytool error: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No certificate data found

I want to record script through Jmeter, I have java 19 installed on my system and set proxy in firfox broswer